# Is it possible to configure the Linux kernel I/O scheduler for an NFS mount?

Tags: linux, nfs, kernel, io

On a normal block device you can change the i/o scheduler like this:

```
# cat /sys/block/hda/queue/scheduler
noop anticipatory deadline [cfq]
# echo anticipatory > /sys/block/hda/queue/scheduler
# cat /sys/block/hda/queue/scheduler
noop [anticipatory] deadline cfq
```

How can I control the setting for a NFS volume or do I just have to set it globally in the boot config with

```
elevator=noop
```

or similar?

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not possible. 

NFS is providing a network mount and is outside of the block-device scheduler settings.

Comment: Will it be affected by the global io scheduler change though? I assume so since the kernel still manages io to NFS